# Sum of two squares and prime factorizations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

If $m$ is a positive integer such that every prime factor of $m$ that is
congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ appears with an even power, then $m$ can be written
as a sum of two squares.

I wrote $m=2^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}q_1^{b_1}\dots q_l^{b_l}$ where each $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and each $q_j \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $b_j$ are even. I am not sure what to do next... I know that each $2$ factor $=(1^2+1^2)$ which is a sum of squares and that if m equals the product of many sums of squares then m is a sum of squares but I am not sure how to show that the $p_i^{a_i}$ factors and $q_j^{b_j}$ factors are all sums of squares...

Comment: Unless  m is a power of 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align}
(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2
\end{align}
This means if two numbers can be written as the sum of squares, then their product can also be written as the sum of squares. Consider the $q_j$. Each $b_j$ is even so write $b_j = 2b'_j$. We then have $q_j^{b_j} = (q_j^{b'_j})^2 + 0^2$ so each of them can be written as the sum of sqaures. Thus $q_1^{b_1} \cdots q_l^{b_l}$ can be written as the sum of squares. Similarly be Fermat's theorem on the sum of squares each $p_i$ can be written as the sum of squares, and thus $p_i^{a_i}$ can be written as the sum of squares. Also $2 = 1^2 + 1^2$. Thus the product $m = 2p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k} q_1^{b_1} \cdots q_l^{b_l}$ can be written as the sum of squares.

Comment: thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It must be possible that  $ad-bc\ne 0. $This is not possible if $a^2+b^2$ and $c^2+d^2 $are odd powers of $2$. A power of $4$ is not the sum of two squares.

Comment: @user254665 I think the case of $0^2 + a^2$ still counts since sum of squares usually refers to sum of integer squares. Even on OEIS(sequence A001481) the sequence of sums of squares includes powers of 4, such as 16.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Step 1: Prove that $2$ and every prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv 1\pmod 4$ can be represented as sum of two squares.

Step 2: Prove that if $a$ and $b$ can be represented as sum of two squares, $ab$ can be also written as sum of two squares.

Step 3: Now you get $m=(x^2+y^2)\prod_qq_i^{b_i}=(x^2+y^2)z^2$ because all of the $b_i$s are even.